# listview selecteditem as T command paramenter when event is Tapped gives a type cast exception

Tags: c#, wpf, uwp, command

I have a ListView that is bound to a collection i.e. `List<InnerGridItems>` in my case. Problem is when I try to bind the SelectedItem to the CommandParameter, sometimes it gives a typecast exception saying Unable to typecast from Windows.UI.TappedEventArgs to InnerGridItems. (The concept is same for both WPF and UWP, there there is a Click event,so I am adding the WPF tag). Please help.

Xaml:

```
<ListView Margin="0,10,0,0" x:Name="lstInnerItems" Grid.Row="1" 
          ItemsSource="{Binding InnerBarCodeItems, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" 
          SelectionMode="Single"
          HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch"
          Tag="{Binding ElementName=ImgFlash}">
     <Interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
         <Core:EventTriggerBehavior EventName="Tapped">
             <Core:InvokeCommandAction 
                   Command="{Binding ListSelectionChangedCommand,Mode=OneWay}" 
                   CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=lstInnerItems, Path=SelectedItem}"></Core:InvokeCommandAction>
         </Core:EventTriggerBehavior>
     </Interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
     <ListView.ItemTemplate>
         <DataTemplate>
              <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                  <RadioButton x:Name="rbnEnumerated" GroupName="A" 
                               IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
                      <Interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
                          <Core:DataTriggerBehavior Binding="{Binding IsVisible, Mode=TwoWay}" Value="False">
                              <Core:ChangePropertyAction TargetObject="{Binding ElementName=rbnEnumerated}" PropertyName="Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
                          </Core:DataTriggerBehavior>
                          <Core:DataTriggerBehavior Binding="{Binding IsVisible, Mode=TwoWay}" Value="True">
                              <Core:ChangePropertyAction TargetObject="{Binding ElementName=rbnEnumerated}" PropertyName="Visibility" Value="Visible" />
                          </Core:DataTriggerBehavior>
                      </Interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
                  </RadioButton>
                  <TextBlock Text="{Binding SerialNumber}" Margin="10,0,0,0"></TextBlock>
                  <TextBlock Margin="14,0,0,0">
                      <Run Text="("></Run>
                      <Run Text="{Binding SerialPort}"></Run>
                      <Run Text=")"></Run>
                  </TextBlock>
              </StackPanel>
          </DataTemplate>
      </ListView.ItemTemplate>
  </ListView>
```

Here is my model class

InnerGridItems.cs

```
public class InnerGridItems : BindableBaseThreadSafe
    {
        private string _serialNumber = "N/A";
        public string SerialNumber
        {
            get => _serialNumber;
            set => Set(ref _serialNumber, value);
        }
        private string _serialPort = "N/A";
        public string SerialPort
        {
            get => _serialPort;
            set => Set(ref _serialPort, value);
        }
        private bool _isChecked;
        public bool IsChecked
        {
            get => _isChecked;
            set => Set(ref _isChecked, value);
        }
        private MemoryStream _flashedBarCodeImage;
        public MemoryStream FlashedBarCodeImage
        {
            get => _flashedBarCodeImage;
            set => Set(ref _flashedBarCodeImage, value);
        }
        private bool _isVisisble = true;
        public bool IsVisible
        {
            get => _isVisisble;
            set => Set(ref _isVisisble, value);
        }

    }
```

Here is my ICommand

```
public ICommand ListSelectionChangedCommand { get; set; }
 private void FlashImageForSelectedRow(InnerGridItems obj)
        {
         //Gives an exception that it cannot type cast to InnerGridItems.
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

If this is an intermittent issue, You might try checking the cast before performing it using the `is` or `as` operator/keyword, or otherwise catching the exception.  `as` is better, because it does fewer casts ([Is versus as discussion](https://davidzych.com/avoid-using-the-is-keyword-in-c/))

Using `as`:

```
var items = eventArgs as InnerGridItems;
if(items != null)
{
    //do stuff with items!
}
else
{
     //do nothing, or whatever you want to handle this condition
}
```

Using `is`:

```
if( eventArgs is InnerGridItems)
{ 
    var items = eventArgs as InnerGridItems;
    //do stuff with items!
}
else // this could allow you to do multiple is checks.
{
     //do nothing, or whatever you want to handle this condition
}
```

You would then change your `FlashImageForSelectedRow` method to accept an `object` or `EventArgs` instance, and then perform the `as` / `is` checks inside of that method.

That doesn't answer the deeper question of why this is happening, it would seem that somehow the click event is sometimes not grabbing your `InnerGridItems` instance. 
Unless getting to the bottom of the problem is really important to you (which is totally cool, and please share anything you find!), I think adding a simple check is probably good enough and allows you do spend your time on other things!

Comment: Yes you are right. I even tried raising a manual Tapped event in the xaml.cs and there the SelectedItem is InnerGridItems. This happens intermittently.

Comment: Does it happen consistently for the items in the list view? 
Or is it the result of someone clicking somewhere else on the screen in that UI element.

Comment: It happens very intermittently. Usually when I press the radio Button manually or when I click somewhere outside of the text, then it happens.

Comment: I can't even handle the exception because, when it occurs it breaks at the RelayCommand class even before executing the method for the RelayCommand.

Comment: When you change your FlashImageForSelectedRow method to accept an Object type property,like:`private void FlashImageForSelectedRow(object myobj){}` instead of InnerGridItems and then press the radio Button, will the exception occur? I tested it, it worked well. If the exception still occur, can you provide some snippet code about your implementation of Command?